# "Illegal choice full_html in Text format element" when submitting form programatically

Tags: forms

Im trying to create a block programatically. I have created a function, which does the work for me.

```
function _create_footer_contact() {

  form_load_include($form_state, 'inc', 'block', 'block.admin');

  $form_state = array();
  $form_state['values'] = array(
    'machine_name' => 'footer_contact',
    'title' => 'TITLE',
    'info' => 'INFO',
    'body' => array(
      'value' => 'BODY TEXT',
      'format' => 'full_html',
    ),
    'regions' => array(
      'mytheme' => 'footer',
      'myadmintheme' => '-1',
    ),
    'visibility' => '0',
    'pages' => NULL,
    'custom' => '0'
  );

  drupal_form_submit('block_add_block_form', $form_state);
}
```

The problem is the 'format' value, which throws an error if it is set to anything but 'plain_text' (if format is set to 'plain_text' the form submits nicely and a block is created).

```
WD form: Illegal choice full_html in Text format element. 
An illegal choice has been detected. Please contact the site administrator.
```

To debug I have tried to examine the $form_state of 'block_add_block_form' using hook_form_alter and dpm(). When I manually submit a block the 'format' is set to 'full_html'.

So... how do I submit a form programatically with full_html set as format?

Comment: That error happens when the value provided for an input doesn't match the options available when the form was built. Is full_html definitely an option on that form in the same context?

Comment: Yes it is. If I create a block manually (and examine $form_state with dpm() in hook_form_alter), format is set to full_html.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.It works i think so

```
$form['formItem'] = array(
     '#type'=>'text_format',
     '#title' => t('Field Label'),
     '#value' => 'This is my value',
     '#format'=>'full_html',
);
```